# Как получить значения JSON в WebApp2

Tags: python, json, webapp2

Столкнулся с проблемой получения данных из Json в WebApp2:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([Route('/test_addr', test_addr, 'test_addr')])

class test_addr(BaseWebHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
        print('name=', name)
```

Через постман отправляю:

```
{"name": "тест дата"}
```

В постмане - пусто. А в принте:

```
('name=', '')
```

Вроде все как в [документации](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html), но не работает.

Кто работал с WebApp2 - как взять мне взять значение из Json по ключу `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
import json
def get_objJson(requestData):
    return json.loads(requestData.body)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([Route('/test_addr', test_addr, 'test_addr')])

class test_addr(BaseWebHandler):
    def post(self):
        objJson = get_objJson(requestData=self.request)
        print('name=', objJson['name'])
```