# Почему когда я пытаюсь отправить файлы в форме с помощью jQuery файлы не приходят?

Tags: python, jquery, django

У меня есть форма с отправкой данных через jQuery которые принимает функция Python.
Но когда я отправляю форму их там нет.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/main/images/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main/css/Base.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Добавить новость с Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="top-menu">
    <a class="navbar-logo" href="/"><img id="logo" src="/static/main/images/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.png" height="40"></a>
    <ul class="menu-main">
        
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-profile/dead_neon"><img src="media/avatars/dead_neon.png" width="50" class="ico"></a>
        
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul id="navbar">
    
        <li><a href="/news" >Новости</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/" >Главная</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/Create_Player_News" >Написать новость</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/" >Сервера</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/" >Просмотрщик</a></li>
    
</ul>


<div id="post-form">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="cXy1EMeIlcs4F6zx6OGEa071enzp5JqJB07JsdUlqBlNoRx2nrEkmLSBFPCzrzFG">
        <p><label for="id_text_field">Text field:</label> <input type="text" name="text_field" maxlength="400" required id="id_text_field"></p>
<p><label for="id_file_field">File field:</label> <input type="file" name="file_field" multiple id="id_file_field"></p>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#post-form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($('#id_file_field')[0].files)
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/posts_all2',
            data:{
                text_field:$('#id_text_field').val(),
                file_field:$('#id_file_field')[0].file,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```py
# Python обработчик

def PlayerNews(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            files = form.files.getlist('file_field')
            print(form.files.getlist('file_field'))
            print(request.FILES.getlist('file_field'))
            p = Posts(content=form.cleaned_data['text_field'], user_id=request.user)
            #p.save()
            for f in files:
                print("A")
                print(f)
                File = Posts_Files(user_id=request.user, post_id=p, file=f)
                #File.save()
        return HttpResponse('You write new post')
    else:
        form = AddPostForm
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        w = Mine.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    else:
        w = ""
    return render(request, 'main/Player_News_gquery.html', {'form': form, 'Title': 'Добавить новость с Jquery', 'menu_vertical': menu, 'Users': w})
```

Comment: Я в своем вопросе разбирал работу с формой - может поможет Вам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367034/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-json-%d0%b2-webapp2

Comment: Код должен быть в вопросе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> console.log($('#id_file_field')[0].files)
> ```

> ```
> file_field:$('#id_file_field')[0].file,
> ```

Должгно быть так:

```
file_field: $('#id_file_field')[0].files[0],
```

А ещё ты не проставил `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Если мне все файлы нужны?

Comment: @Отображаемоеимя, в `multipart/form-data` можно отправлять несколько файлов. Выстави его и попробоуй просто `file_field: $('#id_file_field')[0].files` (не знаю, получится или нет), но в любом случае в твоём коде буквы `s` не хватает.

Comment: file_field: $('#id_file_field')[0].files не работает